# How to add a flash light to a particle explosion

Tags: unity, lighting, particles

I've an explosion effect using particle system.

Explosion occur on air, so I want to add a "flash" light effect when explosion occur (that light sky and terrain ).

Can you suggest me best way to obtain ?

Thanks

Comment: Presumably you tried adding a point light and adjusting its brightness along an animation curve? Or [adding a sub-system with a lights module](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysLightsModule.html)? How did these attempts work out for you so far? What concretely did you try, and where did you run into an obstacle you need help overcoming?

Comment: Exactly: finally i've added a point light and a routine that increment (and decrement) intensity and range. And yes.. I can say result is good.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an answer that can help other developers. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just added a point light with a script that increase (then decrease) :

- intensity
- range

in a fixed span time .

This is my script:

```
public class gsFlashLightExplosion : MonoBehaviour
```

{
    [SerializeField] int LightStartRange;

```
[SerializeField] int LightEndRange;

[SerializeField] float LightStartIntensity;

[SerializeField] float LightEndIntensity;

[SerializeField] float Speed;

private bool blnRun=true;

private Light light;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    light=GetComponent<Light>();
    light.range = LightStartRange;
    light.intensity = LightStartIntensity;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if(LightEndRange>light.range)
        light.range = (int)(light.range + (light.range * Speed / 100));
    else
        light.range = (int)(light.range - (light.range * Speed / 100));

    if (LightEndIntensity > light.intensity)
        light.intensity = light.intensity + (light.intensity * Speed / 100);
    else
        light.intensity = light.intensity - (light.intensity * Speed / 100);


}
```

}